# T-SLQ Can you use aggregate in on clause?

Tags: sql, t-sql, ssms

I have 2 call tables. Table 1 has call/client info. Table 2 has the call logs, what happened during call. I need to join table 2 to table 1 but only pull the 'Time' for the first phone. There are multiple 'Phone's in the call logs, need the time for the first one.

```
Table 1                             Table 2                                       Goal

Call ID  Client  State            Call ID   Method     Time           Call ID   Client  State  Time
1        John    TX               1         Inbound    11:00          1         John    TX     11:01
2        Mike    CA               1         Phone      11:01          2         Mike    CA     11:31
3        Susan   NA               1         Answer     11:01          3         Susan   NA     ...   
4        ...     ....             1         Phone2     11:05          4
                                  1         Call End   11:22          .         etc
                                  2         Inbound    11:30
                                  2         Phone      11:31
```

Kinda want to do something like this.

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1 on Table2 t2 = t1.call_id = t2.call_id and t2.Method like '%Phone%'
```

but this will pull all the phones times. Need MIN(phone). Can you use an aggregate in on clause?

Answer (score 0):

No, you cannot use an aggregation in an `on` clause.  Instead, use `apply`:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table1 t1 CROSS APPLY
     (SELECT TOP (1) t2.*
      FROM Table2 t2 
      WHERE t2.call_id = t1.call_id and 
            t2.Method like '%Phone%'
      ORDER BY phone
     ) t2;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
select t1.*, t2.time
from table1 t1 inner join (
  select *, row_number() over (partition by callid order by time) rn
  from table2
  where method like '%Phone%'
) t2 on t2.callid = t1.callid
where t2.rn = 1
```

or:

```
select t1.*, 
  (select min(time) from table2 where method like '%Phone%' and callid = t1.callid) time
from table1 t1
```